# how to calculate sum based on certain condition

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want to calculate the sum of training hour based on the user name. But when I use function SUM(), it shows a total of all training hour in the database. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    include_once('DB_connect.php');

    $UID = $_SESSION['USERID'];
    if(isset($_POST["USER_NAME"])){
        $B_title  = strtoupper($_POST["USER_NAME"]);
        $sql = "SELECT 
                TS_ID, TS_DATE, TS_DDATE, TS_HOUR, 
                TRAINING_NAME,TRAINING_HOUR, USER_NAME, 
                SUM(B.TRAINING_HOUR) AS TOTAL

            FROM 
                TRAINING_STATUS TS,
                USER_INFO UI,
                TRAINING B
            WHERE
                TS.TRAINING_ID = B.TRAINING_ID
            AND
                TS.USER_ID = UI.USER_ID
            ";

        include('sql.php');

        if(mysql_num_rows($retval) > 0){}
             print   '<table  align="right" style="width:14%">
                            <tr style="background-color:1AB299">
                                <th>TOTAL TRAINING HOUR </th>
                            </tr>';

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    print "<tr style='background-color:BCF9EF'>
                                <th>{$row['TOTAL']}</th>
                            </tr>";
                }
    }
?>
```

Comment: post the code you tried!

Comment: try `group by USER_NAME`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_fetch_array`. This API has been removed. Please upgrade to PHP 7 as soon as possible and use prepared statements.

Comment: Forget about the PHP stuff for now. Instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please show, table structure and sample data.

Answer (score -2):

As **James** pointed out!

Change the query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            TS_ID, TS_DATE, TS_DDATE, TS_HOUR, 
            TRAINING_NAME,TRAINING_HOUR, USER_NAME, 
            SUM(B.TRAINING_HOUR) AS TOTAL

        FROM 
            TRAINING_STATUS TS,
            USER_INFO UI,
            TRAINING B
        WHERE
            TS.TRAINING_ID = B.TRAINING_ID
        AND
            TS.USER_ID = UI.USER_ID
        GROUP BY USER_NAME";
```

Comment: @wawahaniee this returns arbitrary (technically 'indeterminate') values for the training table. Perhaps we have different definitions of 'working'!

Comment: Would you explain what do u mean?